# creating a keystore with trial certificates to get cert chain for signing pdf doc using iText

Tags: android, itext, digital-signature, android-keystore

i have created a CSR using openssl and got trial certificate from thawte,there were three certs.
Now i need those  certificates in chain format to use in android project. I tried appending all content together in a single file (method has been mentioned in may sites) but it is not working.I want ***

> method how can i create keystore (in android i.e .bks) with
>   certificate chain?

---

Thanks

Comment: ??? I assume Thawte has provided a keystore (e.g. a .p12 file), use that keystore. Maybe you're confusing the certificate with the keystore.

Comment: no.. its giving three certificates in a mail, i do understand difference between keystore and certificate.  I tried creating a .p12 file and .p7b file but its not working. Android require .bks keystore file i have worked on android keystores in 2-3 projects. Kindly if u tell how to create .p12 file from 3 different files those are leaf, intermediate & root CA certs ? Thanks

Comment: Private key i have created, i hope this will not come from CA. 3 certs contents i got in mail i stored them in .cer format

Comment: Ex--  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEgzCCA2ugAwIBAgIQHSDpIar4pGe/QshLosZFUTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
qDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDFRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
Q2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBTZXJ2aWNlcyBEaXZpc2lvbjEwMC4GA1UECxMnRm9yIFRl
-----END CERTIFICATE-----